# How to get JSON response after onPresseed button in Flutter // Dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-async, flutter-http

**I don't get any issues to get JSON data the button is pressed to get JSON response.body is printed successfully but the JSON response is executed before I give _addressController value the if condition executed so the exception is shown on the print state. so please see my code and help me to overcome the issues**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;
import 'string.dart';



void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Retrieve Text Input',
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

 class _MyAppState extends State<MyCustomForm> {

   final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

   var url1 = 'This is my first off url';
  
   var _addressControler = TextEditingController();
   late Future<Balance> futureBalance;



   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     futureBalance = fetchBalance();
   }

   Future<Balance> fetchBalance() async {
    
     http.Response response =
     await http.get(Uri.parse(url1+_addressControler.text));

     print(response.body);

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       return Balance.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
     } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Fetch Data Example',
         theme: ThemeData(
           primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
         ),
         home: Scaffold(
           
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
           ),
           body: Center(
             key: _formKey,
             child: Column(
                 children: [
                   Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                     child: TextField(
                       controller: _addressControler,
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                         labelText: 'Enter the address...',
                         labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                         border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                             borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                     child: ElevatedButton(
                       onPressed: () async {
                         await fetchBalance();
                       },
                       child: const Text('Submit'),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                     child: Text("${_addressControler.text}"),

                   ),
                   Container(
                     //color: Colors.blueAccent,
                     child: FutureBuilder<Balance>(
                       future: futureBalance,
                       builder: (context, index) {
                         if (index.hasData) {
                           print(index.data!.height);
                           var x = (index.data!.result[0].amount);
                           var y = int.parse(x);
                           assert(y is int);
                           var z = (y / 1000000);
                           print(z); 
                           return Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                               children: [
                                 Text('${z.toString()}',
                                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,),),
                               ]);
                         } else if (index.hasError) {
                           return Text("${index.error}");
                         }
                       
                         return CircularProgressIndicator();
                       },
                     ),
                   ),
                 ]
             ),
           ),
         )
     );
   }
 }
```

I have an issue on **fetchBalance()** function. The **if** the condition is executed before I click the **onPressed** button but **I what to do after given TextField and submit onPressed to execute the condition**. so, is any possible way to overcome this issue please help me...

Comment: try using `futureBalance = await fetchBalance();` in your `initState`

Comment: This one is not working the 'initState' is not get await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up all I remove the `initState()` and i use `setState()` for `onPressed()` to call the API function `fetchBalance()` on the state it's working good..

```
child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: ()  {
                      setState(() {
                        fetchBalance();
                      });
                      fetchBalance();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but it seems you get an error because `fetchBalance` is executed before you expect it to.

Well, you call `futureBalance = fetchBalance();` within your `initState()` method, hence the code is executed when your widget is being initialized and not only after you press the button. This means, you try to parse the url without appending `_addressControler.text`.

Comment: if any possible way to get JSON without 'initState()' in flutter 2.0. if it is possible give me a reference link.

Comment: You are calling fetchBalance again in your onPressed, which is correct, but you are not assigning the futureBalance there. Try ´futureBalance = await fetchBalance()´ in your onPressed and remove the line from initState.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use it like this.

```
 fetchBalance().then((balance) {
      setState(() {
        _balance = balance; //need to create one variable of type Balance
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better put the setState() in your async call:

```
 Future<Balance> fetchBalance() async {
    
     http.Response response =
     await http.get(Uri.parse(url1+_addressControler.text));

     print(response.body);

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         setState(() {
             _balance = Balance.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
         });
     } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
   }
```